# Google Sign In for Websites causing "Signature verification failed" with JWT PHP library

Tags: javascript, php, google-api-php-client, google-signin

Google web sign in has driven me positively crazy...

I'm building a simple web application, and I'm trying to integrate Google's sign in feature into the website (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/).

The JavaScript seemed to go fairly well, and the next step was to verify the `id_token` I was receiving with my backend server (again, against Google's recommendation: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth).

It's a PHP-based web application, and I've successfully installed the Google Client API library using composer: `composer require google/apiclient`, but when posting my `id_token` value to my PHP backend system I'm consistently receiving the following error:

```
Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException
File: .\vendor\firebase\php-jwt\src\JWT.php:112 
Message: Signature verification failed

Stack trace:
#0 .\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\AccessToken\Verify.php(103): Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...', '-----BEGIN PUBL...', Array)
#1 .\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(712): Google_AccessToken_Verify->verifyIdToken('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...', '10...')
```

I've also used the `id_token` value on Google's "tokeninfo" endpoint (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=ABC123), and the `id_token` validates perfectly, so I'm sure it's not the `id_token` value that's wrong. It's also passing it perfectly via the POST variable to the PHP script, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Here's my code:

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=googleAppStart" async defer></script>
<script>
    var googleAppStart  = function(){gapi.load('auth2', initGoogleSignIn);};
    var auth            = false;
    function initGoogleSignIn(){
        auth = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id   : 'client-id-is-here',
            scope       : 'profile'
        });

        auth.attachClickHandler(document.getElementById('my-button'));
        auth.isSignedIn.listen(googleSignInChanged);
        auth.currentUser.listen(googleCurrentUserChanged);

        if (auth.isSignedIn.get() == true)
            auth.signIn();
    }

    function googleSignInChanged(signed_in){}
    function googleCurrentUserChanged(user){
        var auth_response   = user.getAuthResponse();
        var id_token        = auth_response.id_token;
        if (id_token != undefined){
            var url     = '/verify-google-signin';
            var params  = {id_token: id_token};
            jQuery.post(url, params, function(data){}, 'json');
        }
    }
</script>
```

...and my PHP catching the POST:

```
<?php

    require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $credentials = array("client_id" => "client-id-is-here");
    $client = new \Google_Client($credentials);

    $data = $_POST;
    if (isset($data['id_token'])) {

        $id_token = trim($data['id_token']);

        // Exception generated here...
        $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
    }

?>
```

Thank you so much for taking the time to read this, and for any assistance! It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be a recurring problem with the `dev-master / 2.x-dev` and `2.2.0` versions of the `google/apiclient` composer package. I removed the latest version, and ran: `composer require google/apiclient:2.1.3` and it's working flawlessly now. I'd love to know what the issue is however.

Comment: Just had the same problem with the same build. Really puzzling

Comment: Just experienced this as well, just yesterday everything was perfect, now: `Uncaught Exception 'Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException' with message 'Signature verification failed'`. Does anyone know what causes this ?

Comment: Now it works, i didn't do anything.

Comment: The error is back! Again, didn't do anything.

Comment: Anyone got a solution?

Comment: @Chris Kempen can you tell how can i pass state parameter along with request?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue today.

Easier if you just execute:

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt:4.0
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I just implemented this and then it suddenly broke... maybe because of the random token there was some kind of matching problem? Thank you for this amazing solution!

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately you can verify `id_token` without google library as described here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint

```
    if (isset($data['id_token'])) {
        $id_token = trim($data['id_token']);
        try {
            $res = (new \GuzzleHttp\Client())->request('GET',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo', [
                    'query' => ['id_token' => $id_token],
                ]);
            $payload = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
            //you still need to check that the aud claim contains one of your app's client IDs
            if ($payload['aud'] != "client-id-is-here") {
                throw new \Exception("App Isn't valid", 422);
            }

        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            //IF token isn't valid you will be here
            if ($e->hasResponse()) {
                /** @var \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response $resp */
                $resp = $e->getResponse();
                $error = json_decode($resp->getBody()->getContents(), true)['error_description'];
                throw new \Exception($error, $resp->getStatusCode());
            }
        }
    }
```

If you have no exceptions then your token is valid

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem with php-jwt. Latest version is not working with Google Api Client.

Try to use php-jwt version 4.

I put "firebase/php-jwt": "<5.0" in my composer.json file.

Worked as a charm!

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in [v2.2.1](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases/tag/v2.2.1) of google/apiclient so make sure you are running this version or later if anyone else encounters this issue.

Related discussions [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1286) and [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1279).

Answer (score 1):

I've got problems with Google Sign-In backend authentication yesterday, using both google/apiclient 2.2.0 and 2.1.3.

**tl;dr it was most likely malfunctions on the Google side or some obscure limits I'm unaware of (nothing in the Developer Console about that).**

First, the "idToken" Google was giving me client-side was not a valid JWT: openssl_verify() was rejecting it in Firebase\JWT\JWT, throwing a Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException. I followed your advice, installed google/apiclient 2.1.3 and this exception was not being throwed anymore but the resulting payload was null (so the idToken was still invalid).

A few hours later, I had experienced intermittent results with the apiclient 2.3.0: sometimes the token was invalidated by signature verification (and throwing the signature exception) and sometimes the token was cryptographically valid but the returned payload was null. Once in a while, the token was valid (!).

In the end, the backend authenticaton process was succeeding every time.

As I began experiencing these problems, I tried to fix it generating new OAuth2 keys, revert to a previous verions of my codebase (both server-side and client-side) that I knew was working, removed all browser data and tried to get the token on Cordova with the Sign In for Android. Nothing worked. Also no message in the Developer Console, no visible limits, no security e-mail.

If it's not a bug but a feature, the error handling is quite harsh :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Max, I'd tend to agree with you, although in my case Google's `tokeninfo` endpoint _was_ validating my JWT correctly, whereas their PHP implementation wasn't with the _same_ JWT...really strange...

Comment: Same problem @ChrisKempen, works via the endpoint, but not using the Google PHP Library

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Firebase (taken from https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)

```
 rm -r vendor/google/apiclient-services
```

Add this to composer.json

```
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    },
    "extra": {
        "google/apiclient-services": [
            "Drive"  ,
            "... any other services here ...",
      ]
    }
```

Finally

```
composer install
```

This will resolve the error message with the added benefit of drastically reducing installed packages. As noted, there are at least 200 API services for GAPI